# Is this expected behavior for Perl smart match?

Tags: regex, perl

```
### Code Here ###

use 5.012;
use warnings;
my @a = (1, 'Ah');

say (@a ~~ /^1$/ ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
say ('1' ~~ @a ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
say (@a ~~ "Ah" ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
say (@a ~~ /^Ah$/ ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');

### STDOUT ###

TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

Shouldn't all of these pass?

Comment: What about '"Ah" ~~ @a'?

Comment: `say ("Ah"~~ @a ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');` will pass

Comment: What version of Perl are you using and "use v5.x" did you put into the code?

Comment: But then I get `Argument "Ah" isn't numeric in smart match`

Comment: I added imports above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smartmatch's behavior is generally determined by the type of the *right* operand; it's not symmetrical.  Keep the array on the right side and you should see the behavior you expect.

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator):

> It is often best read aloud as "in", "inside of", or "is contained in", because the left operand is often looked for *inside* the right operand. That makes the order of the operands to the smartmatch operand often opposite that of the regular match operator. In other words, the "smaller" thing is usually placed in the left operand and the larger one in the right.

Giving this a read over again, honestly the behavior seems a bit bizarre and unpredictable, and I'd limit my use of it to either well-documented helper functions or extremely trivial cases.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna have to agree

Comment: It's well documented to be experimental now :)

Comment: With so many ways it can be used and an unfortunate name like 'Smart' match, people expect way too much DWIMitude from it.  The poor feature was set up for failure.  As with other complex features, like `pack` or `printf`, one should probably keep the docs on hand when using it until you're quite familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Smartmatch is a subtle beast, and the Perl5 implementation is arguably buggy – it was demoted to experimental status in the 5.18 release.

We can look at the [table of possible type combinations](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) to determine which case is chosen.

- The `@a ~~ /^1$/` has type `ARRAY ~~ Regexp` which has the description “any ARRAY elements match Regexp. Like: `grep { /Regexp/ } ARRAY`”.
- The `'1' ~~ @a` has type `Any ~~ ARRAY`, which has the description “smartmatch each ARRAY element. Like: `grep { Any ~~ $_ } ARRAY`”. The second level of smart matches should use the `Any ~~ Num` and `Any ~~ Any` cases.
- The `@a ~~ "Ah"` probably has type `Any ~~ Any`, which does string comparison!
- The `@a ~~ /^Ah$/` is the above regex case again.

The smartmatch table is best understood by looking at the right argument. If it is a collection, the smartmatch is an `in` operator. If it is a regex or a coderef, smartmatch behaves like an application. If it is a simple scalar, then a ordinary comparision (either `==` or `eq`) is done.